# I have a line plot describing forecast of historical data, I want to add the confidence interval as a shaded region

Tags: r, plot

The line plot is given as such -

[Line plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuQeU.png)

Now, I have a dataframe which has both the mean and confidence interval as columns. I wanted to add the confidence interval as a shaded region around the line plot.

I tried to add the confidence interval using polygon but it gave me separate lines including the confidence interval as a curve and shaded region.
[Using Polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWH8d.png)

The code for the same is given below -

```
plot(row.names(df),df$`Point Forecast`,xlab='30 days of forecast',ylab='Cases',type='l',lwd=2,col='blue')
polygon(x=row.names(df),y=df$`Hi 95`,col=rgb(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.25))
polygon(x=row.names(df),y=df$`Lo 95`,col=rgb(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.25))
```

The dataframe is as such -

```
    Forecast       Low      High Days
1   93380.13  88617.45  98142.81  229
2   98406.60  93269.62 103543.58  230
3  101944.17  96715.20 107173.14  231
4  104451.55  99062.35 109840.74  232
5  104548.60  98916.06 110181.15  233
6  101948.87  96160.04 107737.70  234
7  100730.13  93877.35 107582.91  235
8  102627.38  94483.51 110771.26  236
9  105946.54  96958.65 114934.44  237
10 109369.26  99772.87 118965.65  238
11 111689.54 101513.19 121865.88  239
12 111629.45 100986.24 122272.65  240
13 110281.26  98925.13 121637.39  241
14 109906.05  97426.23 122385.88  242
15 111292.69  97583.75 125001.63  243
16 113973.91  99178.07 128769.75  244
17 116971.84 101210.18 132733.51  245
18 118885.46 102302.11 135468.81  246
19 119120.52 101724.31 136516.73  247
20 118590.55 100197.20 136983.90  248
21 118600.11  98993.22 138207.00  249
22 119812.74  98914.34 140711.14  250
23 122108.28  99949.76 144266.81  251
24 124617.50 101305.57 147929.43  252
25 126289.40 101920.54 150658.26  253
26 126815.90 101377.10 152254.71  254
27 126784.58 100156.77 153412.39  255
28 127066.83  99119.44 155014.21  256
29 128235.71  98896.34 157575.08  257
30 130220.61  99501.05 160940.17  258
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be using `ggplot2`. You can add a ribbon for the high and low confidence limits with `geom_ribbon()`. Here the code.

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(df,aes(x = Point, y = Forecast)) +
  geom_line(color = "#14243e") +
  geom_ribbon(
    aes(ymin = Low, ymax = High),
    fill = 'midnightblue',
    alpha = 0.2)
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Point = 229:258, Forecast = c(93380.13, 98406.6, 
101944.17, 104451.55, 104548.6, 101948.87, 100730.13, 102627.38, 
105946.54, 109369.26, 111689.54, 111629.45, 110281.26, 109906.05, 
111292.69, 113973.91, 116971.84, 118885.46, 119120.52, 118590.55, 
118600.11, 119812.74, 122108.28, 124617.5, 126289.4, 126815.9, 
126784.58, 127066.83, 128235.71, 130220.61), Low = c(88617.45, 
93269.62, 96715.2, 99062.35, 98916.06, 96160.04, 93877.35, 94483.51, 
96958.65, 99772.87, 101513.19, 100986.24, 98925.13, 97426.23, 
97583.75, 99178.07, 101210.18, 102302.11, 101724.31, 100197.2, 
98993.22, 98914.34, 99949.76, 101305.57, 101920.54, 101377.1, 
100156.77, 99119.44, 98896.34, 99501.05), High = c(98142.81, 
103543.58, 107173.14, 109840.74, 110181.15, 107737.7, 107582.91, 
110771.26, 114934.44, 118965.65, 121865.88, 122272.65, 121637.39, 
122385.88, 125001.63, 128769.75, 132733.51, 135468.81, 136516.73, 
136983.9, 138207, 140711.14, 144266.81, 147929.43, 150658.26, 
152254.71, 153412.39, 155014.21, 157575.08, 160940.17)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Comment: I tried doing as your code but it's giving me an empty plot and an error saying - `geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you
need to adjust the group aesthetic?`

Comment: @SAIFULMEHDI First try with the data I shared `df` and reproduce the code. I suspect you have to load `tidyverse` library.

Comment: I did it with your data and it gave as you have shown but for my data it isn't showing as such

Comment: @SAIFULMEHDI Nice, so there must be an issue with your variable names. Do you have the same names as in the data you provided? Please check `names(yourdf)` and let me know the output or move to chat with this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187426/how-do-i-chat-with-another-user-on-stackoverflow

Comment: The name of the second column is Point Forecast and the first column is the index

Comment: You have to enquote the names when they have spaces with ``

Comment: I have modified the dataframe. But still it's giving me an empty plot

Comment: @SAIFULMEHDI It is strange I think the names are the issue, try leaving the same names as `df` for your real data, or move to chat in order to help you!

Comment: I have low reputation, so I cannot move to chat

Comment: @SAIFULMEHDI All people can do, just check the link I shared with you!

Comment: @SAIFULMEHDI Wait, you shared new data, right?

Comment: Data is the same but the names of the column have been modified

Comment: @SAIFULMEHDI try `ggplot(df,aes(x=Days,y=Forecast))+geom_line(color = "#14243e") +geom_ribbon(
    aes(ymin = Low, ymax = High),
    fill = 'midnightblue',
    alpha = 0.2)`

Comment: @SAIFULMEHDI Added a new option in comments! Please check if that works!

Comment: Nope, it's still giving an empty plot

Comment: @SAIFULMEHDI The issue must be the names, please check about the chat. Please use `names(yourdf)` and share the output in a comment!

Comment: names(df)
`[1] "Forecast" "Low"      "High"     "Days"`

Comment: @SAIFULMEHDI Try re starting `R` and only load your data and `ggplot2`. It might be an issue with other package, alaso adjust the names for each variable in the `ggplot` design!

Comment: I did it and I tried plotting a histogram using `geom_histogram`, it did plot but when I am trying to plot a line using `geom_line` I'm getting the error `geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you
need to adjust the group aesthetic?`

Comment: @SAIFULMEHDI Try adding `group=1` in the first `aes()` or `group=Days`